# stripe is not defined but I have clearly defined it in my angular project

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

in my stripecreditcardcomponent.html

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const stripe   = Stripe('removed secret');
  const elements = stripe.elements();
</script>
```

my stripecreditcardcomponent.ts

```
async createStripeToken() {
    const {token, error} = await stripe.createToken(this.card);
    if (token) {
      this.onSuccess(token);
    } else {
      this.onError(error);
    }
  }
```

but when my `createstripeToken()` command is called I get the following error:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: stripe is not defined ReferenceError: stripe is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is install npm package, import them in component and use them. For example to use moment I install moment.js npm package, import it in component say `MyComponent` like `declare var moment: any;` then I can use moment in my `MyComponent` like `let date = moment().now()` etc.
Refer this ->https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/stripe-js